# OpenGL project gives error "Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)"

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake

So I'm using Clion and doing an OpenGL tutorial. First I copied some basic code over to make sure cmake was setup correctly, but it gives me the following error when I run the program: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135). I know this error means it can't find a dll file but I don't know where the file is missing.

## Code

### Here is my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Tetformer)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

set(LIBR_ROOT "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Library")
set(LIB_DIR "${LIBR_ROOT}/lib")
set(INC_DIR "${LIBR_ROOT}/include")
set(BIN_DIR "${LIBR_ROOT}/bin")

set(LIBS glfw3 glew32s glu32 opengl32)

link_directories(${LIB_DIR})
link_directories(${BIN_DIR})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Game.h Game.cpp Texture.h Texture.cpp Shader.h Shader.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBS})

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${INC_DIR})

# opengl
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# glfw
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_libraries(${GLFW_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# glew
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
if (GLEW_FOUND)
    include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_libraries(${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
endif()

# glad
add_library("glad" "${LIBR_ROOT}/src/glad.c")
target_include_directories("glad" PRIVATE "${LIBR_ROOT}/include")
target_include_directories(Tetformer PRIVATE "${LIBR_ROOT}/include")
target_link_libraries(Tetformer "glad" "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")
```

### And here is my main.cpp:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{

    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // uncomment this statement to fix compilation on OS X
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

### My directory that its calling looks like this:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\Game\Tetformer

    07/10/2018  05:32 PM    <DIR>          .
    07/10/2018  05:32 PM    <DIR>          ..
    07/09/2018  10:15 PM             1,431 .gitignore
    07/13/2018  05:44 PM    <DIR>          .idea
    07/10/2018  04:08 PM    <DIR>          cmake
    07/10/2018  05:32 PM    <DIR>          cmake-build-debug
    07/10/2018  05:32 PM             1,223 CMakeLists.txt
    07/09/2018  10:15 PM                73 Game.cpp
    07/10/2018  12:21 AM               339 Game.h
    07/10/2018  02:17 AM    <DIR>          Library
    07/10/2018  05:20 PM             2,965 main.cpp
    07/09/2018  10:15 PM             4,068 Shader.cpp
    07/09/2018  10:15 PM             1,185 Shader.h
    07/09/2018  10:15 PM             1,023 Texture.cpp
    07/09/2018  10:15 PM               335 Texture.h

     Directory of C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\Game\Tetformer\Library

    07/10/2018  02:17 AM    <DIR>          .
    07/10/2018  02:17 AM    <DIR>          ..
    07/09/2018  11:01 PM    <DIR>          bin
    07/10/2018  02:17 AM    <DIR>          include
    07/10/2018  05:01 PM    <DIR>          lib
    07/10/2018  02:17 AM    <DIR>          src


    Directory of C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\Game\Tetformer\Library\lib

    07/10/2018  05:01 PM    <DIR>          .
    07/10/2018  05:01 PM    <DIR>          ..
    07/31/2017  07:42 AM           701,288 glew32.lib
    07/31/2017  07:42 AM         2,584,968 glew32s.lib
    08/18/2016  08:05 AM           279,234 glfw3.dll
    07/10/2018  04:47 PM           317,784 libglad.a
    08/18/2016  08:05 AM           150,452 libglfw3.a
    08/18/2016  08:05 AM            65,788 libglfw3dll.a

    Directory of C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\Game\Tetformer\Library\include

    07/10/2018  02:17 AM    <DIR>          .
    07/10/2018  02:17 AM    <DIR>          ..
    07/31/2017  07:46 AM    <DIR>          GL
    07/10/2018  02:17 AM    <DIR>          glad
    08/18/2016  07:52 AM    <DIR>          GLFW
    05/22/2018  04:35 AM    <DIR>          glm
    07/10/2018  02:17 AM    <DIR>          KHR

    Directory of C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\Game\Tetformer\Library\bin

    07/09/2018  11:01 PM    <DIR>          .
    07/09/2018  11:01 PM    <DIR>          ..
    07/31/2017  07:42 AM           422,912 glew32.dll
    07/31/2017  07:42 AM           539,648 glewinfo.exe
    07/31/2017  07:42 AM           338,432 visualinfo.exe

    Directory of C:\Users\Greg\Desktop\Game\Tetformer\Library\src

    07/10/2018  02:17 AM    <DIR>          .
    07/10/2018  02:17 AM    <DIR>          ..
    07/10/2018  08:17 AM           144,929 glad.c
```

I'm assuming the problem is the cmake file but I cant tell what its missing. The project builds and it has all the appropriate Find.cmake files, but when you hit run it returns an exit code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Look up the error code. Read through the documentation for the function calls involved. Search for online tutorials. Step through your program with a debugger. Don't dump your error messages and code here and expect us to do the above.

Comment: A tool called dependencywalker may be of help.

Comment: Dependancy walker was super helpful. Apparently I am missing alot of files called API_MS_WIN and EXT_MS_WIN

Edit: Nevermind turns out those were false positives and are not missing

Answer (score 1):

If your program builds successfully and on startup complains about missing .dll file, then you have to copy the .dll file in question to the directory where your .exe is.

Windows usually tell you which .dll file they're missing.

Comment: See thats the thing. It doesn't. All my console prints is the following "Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)"

Answer (score 1):

Okay so BIG thanks to user4581301 for helping me out by mentioning Dependency Walker. It turns out the program couldnt find glew32.dll because it was in the bin folder and not the lib folder. Huge thanks man!